# Is it correct to write "25% off everything"? Should we add "on"?

Tags: of-for, off-of

Is it correct to write "25% off all subscriptions"?

Why are we omitting **on** here?

Comment: Did you want to say '25% off on all subscriptions' ? Usually there is an ellipsis present - '25% off [the price of] all subscriptions'. There is no place for 'on' in the de-ellipted statement.

Comment: But you could say you were going to 'write off 25%, on all subscriptions'. But as a retired accountant, I wouldn't use the term write-off in this instance. In accounts jargon it means something else. I'd say 'we are going to reduce all subs by 25%'. I assume that is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use *on,* inasmuch as all subscriptions have an offer on them (There's 25% off on all subscriptions) but it's unnecessary and introduces an extra hop in processing the sentence.

Instead of [Nigel J's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437549/is-it-correct-to-write-25-off-everything-is-it-grammatically-correct#comment1050449_437549) fairly straightforward ellipsis of what *off* refers to ("There's 25% off [the price of] all subscriptions"), you are adding what *on* refers to as well: "There's **[an offer of]** 25% off [the standard price] on all subscriptions".

It doesn't mean it can't be done, and it's still right to do so, since it is merely another ellipsis; but the additional ellipsis makes the sentence more complicated.

Comment: It seems I got away with 'de-ellipted'.